# Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF when using FAST feature detector in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I am beginner using opencv, and was using the FAST feature detector in opencv to simply get the keypoints of an image.

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d.hpp"

std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> kp;

int main()
{
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("im.jpg", 0);
    cv::FAST(img, kp, 100, true);

    cv::Mat img2;
    cv::drawKeypoints(img, kp, img2 , CV_RGB(255, 0, 0));
    cv::imshow("Display", img2);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    cv::destroyWindow("Display");

    return 0;
}
```

But when debugging the code (Debug mode): 
I found out that the vector kp (passed as the keypoints vector) in to FAST() has a large size ( kp = { size=658812287755660302 }) which is not possible. But the image denoting correct keypoints is generated. The above mentioned access violation error message comes at the end of debugging.

In Release mode:
The code runs fine at first showing the keypoints in the image. At the end when image window is closed, the program is crashed. When debugged, kp has a reasonable size (kp = { size=427 }).

When the code is run in debug mode without debugging, an application error pops out stating that memory at 0xffffffff could not be read.

The call stack is as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNNUr.png), which doesn't make any sense to me.

What am I doing wrong? Is it related to the way I'm initializing the vector or something else?

Comment: Where can we find the image that you're using for testing, `im.jpg`?

Comment: I was not able to reproduce this issue using [this sample image](http://imgur.com/a/2iV3q) with your code. [Result](http://imgur.com/a/MWkIw).

Comment: Check your linker properties. You either linked OpenCV debug library in release, or viceversa. Or you're using a version of OpenCV compiled with a different compiler / architecture

Comment: @Miki I have used the same linker properties that worked for other projects.. And I have included both opencv_world320.lib/320d.lib as additional dependencies which should not give any issue right?

Comment: you need to add **only** opencv_world320.lib in release, and **only** opencv_world320d.lib in debug

Comment: @Miki I tried it.. does not make any difference

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to reproduce this issue either using my own image or using the image you provided. I therefore have to conclude that there's a problem with your build environment.

- Make sure that you've set up your project includes and libraries correctly, including the shared libraries that OpenCV uses by default.
- Make sure that you're using Visual Studio 2015 (or the binary-compatible VS2017) to compile your code.

Comment: I got the same error set even with your image.. But what is the matter with using VS 2013? Other opencv projects worked just fine with it..

Comment: @Heshan You're using OpenCV 3.20 for your project. The shipped binaries for OpenCV 3.20 were compiled for Visual Studio SDK 14.x.yyyy, which corresponds to either VS2015 (14.0.yyyy) or VS2017 (14.1.yyyy), which are binary compatible with each other, but not to other versions of Visual Studio. If you're compiling and building the OpenCV object files yourself using Visual Studio 2013, then you need to inspect the compilation process and make sure you aren't making any mistakes there.

Comment: I did it the other way round by using opencv 2.4.11 (vc12). Now release mode does not make any errors.. But the debug mode gives an opencv error in calling drawkeypoints(). I used `kp.release(1000)` which contains the growth of kp vector to some extent, but larger than that when run in release mode.. What is the link between this abnormal bahavior of the vector object (or FAST() )  and the mode of execution? Now the VS and OpenCV versions could not be the matter, could they?